# To install SQLServer using WebpiCmdLine.exe

Tags: sql-server-2008

For more than 3 hours I am trying to install SQLExpress using `WebPICmdLine.exe`. But it is not installing SQL.  I have attached the log message.  **Are there any prerequisites to be installed ?**

**LOG MESSAGE:**

```
Successfully loaded metadata from feed https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/webproductlist.xml 
Successfully loaded metadata from feed https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/webapplicationlist.xml 
Successfully loaded metadata from feed
```

**Added product SQLExpress to the install list**

```
The following software is going to be installed: 
EULA : 'SQL Server Express 2008 R2', which is owned by 'Microsoft', will be downloaded from 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=186782&clcid=0x0409'. 
The license agreement to 'SQL Server Express 2008 R2' is available at 'http://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/eula/sql_server_2008_r2_express.rtf'. 
Accepted Eulas. 
Started downloading products... 
Started downloading: SQLExpress 
DownloadedSQLExpress 
Started installing Products...  
Started installing: SQLExpress 
Install completed (Failure): SQL Server Express 2008 R2 
SQLExpress : Failed.
```

**Verifying successful installation...**

```
SQL Server Express 2008 R2             False 
  Log Location: %programfiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\Summary.txt 
Install of Products: FAILURE 
Verifying successful log generation... 
SQL Server Express 2008 R2 Logs :          False 
Creation of Product Logs: FAILURE 
Download count: 0 Mb, 0 sec 
Installation count: 1.36 Mb, 52 sec 
Products        , Down. Size, Inst. Time, Down. Time, Inst. Size, Log Size   
SQLExpress      , 58.17     , 52        , 0         , 1.36      , 0      
Total (download size/install time): 58.17 Mb, 52 sec
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known issue with the command-line install of SQLExpress. Based on this exchange (http://forums.iis.net/t/1177882.aspx) there appears to be work being done on the problem, as of May of this year, but no solution.

edit: If you're willing to take the entire SQL Management Studio then this works:

```
WebpiCmdLine.exe /Products:SQLExpressManagementStudio /AcceptEula
```